# visual Studio 2022 Find in All Files has strange File Type Filter

Tags: regex, visual-studio

I was having trouble with the "Find In Files" function in Visual Studio 2022. I was searching in the "Entire Solution", not matching on case or  whole word, not using regular expressions and also including misc. files.

My "File Types" filter was set to the following, which I don't believe I ever manually set:

```
!*\bin\*;!*\obj\*;!*\.*
```

When I searched for `class` or `{`, or any other text in the entire console application solution, no hits were found. For example, there should have been a hit in my program.cs file. Removing the trailing portion of the filter solved the issue.

```
!*\.*
```

This left the following filter which worked:

```
!*\bin\*;!*\obj\*;
```

The question is, what does `!*\.*` mean why did this cause my search to fail?

The following link suggests that it wasn't me who defined this filter (see the screenshot on the page).

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/modernizing-find-in-files/

So, what exactly does this filter do? Does it exclude any file name with a dot in it? Did the way the filter is being used change? I am on version 17.4.4 of VS 2022.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it excludes searching "hidden" config files like `.gitignore`. I just tried to reproduce your problem and indeed the file types mask defaults to `!*\bin\*;!*\obj\*;!*\.*`. Are you sure you had `Include subfolders` checked and that it didn't just find the solution file at a top level?

Comment: @phil Thanks for your reply. I don't see an `include subfolders` option on the "Find In Fies" tab of the "Find and Replace" dialog. I would paste an image if my company did  not prevent this...

Comment: Ah, I see, you had `Look in` set to `Entire solution`. If you switch that to `Current directory` or other then the `Include subfolders` checkbox appears. Seems like my suggestion is off the mark. I can't reproduce your issue with `Entire solution` chosen.